# C++ 3D Physics engine for crushing objects in a simulation

Tags: open-source, library, c++, 3d, simulation

This engine should be able to simulate 3D objects under pressure as close to real life as possible.
I need this for a project where you can spawn a 3D object and then a press will descend and it will apply a force until it breaks.
Similar to this gif:

[image]

It doesn't have to simulate in real life and it would be good if it would have graphic support. It should also be in C++.

If anyone knows any I would be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: real life -> real time, probably

Comment: I think it would be difficult to accurately simulate brittle objects like this, since the strength would be highly influenced by microscopic defects, i.e. resource intensive to simulate accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://projectchrono.org/

This should be sufficient into helping your project.